# Python cannot export to Stata due to unicode problem?

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, stata

I'm trying to export a dataframe in Python as a Stata dta. This is a slimmed version of the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd

df_master = pd.read_stata(old_dta_location)

# Do some data manipulation.

df_master.to_stata(new_dta_location, {"final_date": "td"}, write_index = False)
```

I get the following error when I do this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 11: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I know there are other questions regarding unicode errors but as they are not related to Stata, options such as putting an argument like 'encoding = "utf8"' doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post an example code reproducible; otherwise, help is limited to guessing only.

Comment: If I understand this correctly your error is in python. If so, how does the goal of exporting to Stata enter the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default pandas exports to Stata Version 10 (code 114), which does not support unicode.

Simply specify a later Stata version (118+) to export unicode-columns without error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['€falcon', '€parrot', '€falcon','€parrot']})
df.to_stata('animals.dta', version=118)
```

Answer (score 1):

Stata files can accept UTF-8 data, simply `to_csv` insist on using Latin-1 encoding which does not contain the `€` character. A possible workaround is to use directly a `StataWriterUTF8` object:

```
w = pd.io.stata.StataWriterUTF8('foo.dta', df_master)
w.write_file()
```

Comment: This may need fleshing out with a mention of what version(s) of Stata you are talking about.

Comment: @NickCox: I only speak of the Stata tools provided in a recent Pandas version.

Comment: I don't know more than I say, but presumably there is documentation of what Stata version is supported, and if there isn't there should be. Stata 16.1 is the current version.